# Upload dialog disappears, immediately after it appears, on web page, that I am creating

Tags: javascript, frameworks, web-deployment

I am trying to use [elninotech/uppload](https://github.com/elninotech/uppload), as it looks like it will do what I want (give me a portable, easy to use, powerful file upload button). However when I click on the button, the upload dialog appears and disappears (press pause, in debugger, before pressing button, then single step. On 2nd step dialog appears, on 3rd step it disappears).

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form class="profile">
      <button id="uploadButton">upload image</button>
    </form>
    <img id="profilePicImage"/>
  </body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/uppload/dist/uppload.min.js"></script>
  <script>
const profilePicture = new Uppload({
    value: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/17.jpg",
    bind: ["#profilePicImage"],
    call: ["form.profile button#uploadButton"],
    //endpoint: "https://example.com/upload_backend",
    allowedTypes: "image"
});

  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very complex example on their website https://elninotech.github.io/uppload/ I spent some time debugging, and looking at their code. This is what I found.

An element may have the attribute `data-uppload-button` to mark it as an uppload button. I don't know how that can work with more than one button.

A default button in form dose not work (it causes the problem described in the question). Changing the button to a span works (but is un-intuitive to user). Changing the form to a div, works. Changing the button type to button works.

From the git-hub issue tracker https://github.com/elninotech/uppload/issues/21#issuecomment-445997614

> When you have an HTML form element without a method, it defaults to GET. If it has a button inside it, the form assumes it's a submit button, and therefore refreshes the page on pressing it. This means that if you have button without a type="button", the page is refreshed. This means the original state is reverted and you don't see Uppload open up. That's why you need a type="button" on buttons you don't want to submit the page. Alternately, you can have a event.preventDefault() and return false on the onSubmit event on the form too.

Here is the working code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form class="profile">
      <button type="button" id="uploadButton">upload image</button>
    </form>
    <img id="profilePicImage"/>
  </body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/uppload/dist/uppload.min.js"></script>
  <script>
const profilePicture = new Uppload({
    value: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/17.jpg",
    bind: ["#profilePicImage"],
    call: ["div.profile button#uploadButton"],
    //endpoint: "https://example.com/upload_backend",
    allowedTypes: "image",

    services: ["upload", "camera", "link"],
    crop: {
        startSize: [100,100, "%"]
    }
});

  </script>
</html>
```

I have not yet tested with a working endpoint (server)